# Is it possible to use static DNS servers everywhere EXCEPT specific networks?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, dhcp

I would like to use a DNS server like `1.1.1.1` or OpenDNS or other "private" DNS server on all networks EXCEPT my home one.

This is because I have PiHole enabled on my home network to block ads and malware, and I would like to use that. (Ideally I'd like to use DHCP in this case)

But at the same time, I would prefer to use a trusted DNS server on all other networks to retain a modicum of privacy.

Is this possible on Windows (or any other OS)?

Comment: OpenDNS isn't considered a private DNS server, if want this for privacy reasons, stay away from OpenDNS and Google DNS services.  Solution to your problem is set the outer most networking device to the DNS providers you want to use, and then configure all other devices DNS provider, to the device you configured.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah OpenDNS isn't "private" but its better than my ISP in my opinion. Your suggestion seems to work for stationary systems, but I don't see how that helps my Laptop.